# Is "edit" a noun or verb here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence from a file sharing app:

> You can see details about a folder or file and edit permissions in
>   app's Inspection view.

Here I am confused if the word "edit" is a noun or verb. There are two possibilities:

1. You can see details of "edit permissions."
2. You can edit permissions in the said app's Inspection view.

Which of the above mentioned options is correct here?

Comment: Can you amend, alter, or change permissions using the app?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I have never used this app.

Comment: @curious could you provide more context or cite the source this was taken from?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the source due to confidentiality reasons.

Comment: Why don't you ask them?

Comment: Well, they are not available. I hope to find someone here who has the experience of working with similar apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the sentence is ambiguously formed. The context or the images that come along with the text should help to parse it. It would be helpful if they included a screenshot of the Inspection View.

It could be either a verb

> This procedure explains how to add or edit permissions manually.

or a noun

> If you change a lot of edit or view permissions at once, it might take time before you see the changes.

Nevertheless, I am inclined to think *edit* is used as a verb.

EDIT:

I’ve changed my mind after reviewing Google Drive on my phone. In the context of a file sharing application, “edit permissions” is highly likely to be a menu option.

EDIT 2:

I’ve come round to thinking both versions are equally suitable and I can’t spot a slight difference to distinguish one from another.

Comment: Do you consider "edit permissions" a noun phrase here?

Comment: Yes, that’s what my edit suggests. I am in a real quandary, though.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is ambiguous. The easiest way of correcting it is by simply adding a pronoun.

Either this:

> You can see details about a folder or file and edit **its** permissions in app's Inspection view.

*Edit* is now explicitly a verb.

Or this:

> You can see details about a folder or file and **its** edit permissions in app's Inspection view.

*Edit* is now explicitly an adjective.

Without that, there is no way of knowing, from the sentence alone, what its intended meaning is.